# Реализация кнопки "Выход" с переходом на экран авторизации

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Есть приложение с боковым меню, на котором имеется кнопка "Выход", при нажатии на которую, необходимо выйти из профиля пользователя и перейти на экран авторизации. Каким образом это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну тут может быть миллион вариантов, все зависит от вашей реализации.

Но в общем случае это выглядит так.

1. Пользователь входит в приложение, проверяется токен авторизации (или любой другой параметр определяющий, что пользователь авторизован).

   - Если пользователь не авторизован - отправляем его на авторизацию. После чего закрываем экран авторизации (метод `finish()`) и идем на экран приложения. Важно закрывать экран авторизации, чтоб пользователь при нажатии `back` на клавиатуре не вернулся на него (хотя если вам это поведение подходит, можете оставлять активити в стеке).
   - Если пользователь авторизован - то сразу его направляем в приложение, пропуская экран авторизации.
2. **Выход.** Обычно по нажатию на кнопку "Выход" вы чистите все данные пользователя (токены, можно кэш и другие данные которые относятся к конкретному пользователю). И дальше вы перенаправляете пользователя на экран авторизации. Тут важно опять таки выгрузить из стека все предыдущие активити, чтоб при нажатии на `back` он не вернулся в авторизованную зону.

Comment: спасибо)
Извиняюсь что не по теме, но может подскажите - при использовании библиотеки "mikepenz:materialdrawer", как можно сделать расстояния между элементами ? Например, какой то итем прижать к низу, какой то к верху, а что то зафиксировать по середине

Comment: Не знаю. Никогда не пользовался

Comment: что - ж, во всяком случае - спасибо )